# Google Sign In Button Not Connecting To Google Button Outlet Objective C [Pod Installation]

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-signin, ios9.2

I have followed all procedure same as given in developer google for Google sign in but at the last when they said to connect the outlets, unfortunately, I am unable to do so, please guide me.

[image]

Comment: exactly what you want?

Answer (score 2):

You should have to set Custom class of `UIButton`

- Click on `UIButton`
- Click on show identity inspector
- Set Custom Class to `GIDSignInButton`
  [image: See image]

Comment: yes Ivarun i have did the same as you mentioned above, then too not happening,. http://s31.postimg.org/6yiw2ansr/image.png

Comment: @techno did you import `#import <GoogleSignIn/GoogleSignIn.h>` in .h file ?

Answer (score 2):

I downloaded [this demo](https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services) from GitHub, and I noticed that `GIDSignInButton` is not a `UIButton` but a `UIView`. So you may consider using `UIView` instead of `UIButton`.

Answer (score 0):

please change its class first in the button settings 
from the UIButton to GIDSignInButton
-> [like here](https://www.usebutton.com/img/sdk/img_dlc-configure-class.png)

Answer (score 0):

comment that outlet and start toctrl+drag from that button to that class. from popup give outlet name what you want (exa: singninButton) and press connect. and make sure in assistant editor there is a class opened that you have set to that viewcontroller. hope this will help :)

Comment: yes i can drag and drop and make a UIButton Outlet but Google Sign in says that make a property and then connect to your created button, but it is not connecting. https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/sign-in?configured=true#add_the_sign-in_button

Comment: if you can make that way then do it.  there is nothing compulsory to create property first and then connect

Answer (score 0):

In the action of your UIButton call

GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signOut()

GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signIn()

and it will behave exactly like a GIDSignInButton!